# AngularJS return two http get requests only when resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app, and in the controller I need to call a function which makes two http get requests, and I need this function to return these values just when they are resolved. I cannot make them in the $routeProvider resolve because this function needs a value obtained in the same controller.

I show part of the controller:

```
function myController(info) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.name = info.data.name;

 vm.extra_data = MyService.getExtras(name);
}
```

And here is part of the code of the service:

```
function myService($http, $q, API_EVENT1, API_EVENT2) {
 return {
  getExtras: getExtras
 }

 function getExtras(name) {
  var request1 = API_EVENT1 + '/' + name; 
  var request2 = API_EVENT2 + '/' + name;

 }
}
```

The function is not complete due to I have tried several methods, but I wasn't successful at all.

My problem is how to return (in getExtras function) both of the results of the requests. I have tried using $q.defer, $q.all and promises, but I'm not able to achieve it.

Using $q.all, for example, I got to retrieve the result, but when I call the function, the object extra_data is undefined, due to the requests have been executed asynchronously.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Have you tried to store your `$http responses` to a global variable and use `$q.all()`as just a trigger for when all data is collected?

Comment: I got it! I have tried with that before, but I didn't return the defer correctly, but now I solved it returning the defer previously resolved when the $q.all is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$q.all` to return combined promise from Service, and process result in controller. e.g.:

```
function myService($http, $q, API_EVENT1, API_EVENT2) {
  return {
    getExtras: getExtras
  }
  function getExtras(name) {
    return $q.all([
      $http({method: 'GET', url: API_EVENT1 + '/' + name}), 
      $http({method: 'GET', url: API_EVENT2 + '/' + name})])
     );
  }
}

function myController(info) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = info.data.name;

  MyService.getExtras(name).then(function(data) {
    vm.extra_data.first = data[0];
    vm.extra_data.second = data[1];
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, more or less, but using $q.defer() in the serivce. Indeed, I thoguht I solved in this way, but the problem is that in the controller the vm.extra_data variable is not set in following lines, using .then function as you say. I mean, it is set in this function, with the correct value, but it is undefined in the following lines of the controller.